# How to add click event on d3.js child of collapsible tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using d3.js for collapsible tree structure from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd)
[image]
Now my goal is to add a click event on the final child *(i.e)* **Son of A** or **Daughter of A** 
For example I need to create an alert box on clicking the childless node.
I tried to add a condition within the click function, but it works only on my second click and I don't get it why the alert box is not getting up on my first click.
Could some one explain me why is it so? and what is the right way to do it?

**MY CLICK FUNCTION**

```
function click(d) {
if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;

  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
    if (d.children === null){
        alert(d.id);
    }
  }
update(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
if (d.children === null){
    alert(d.id);
}
```

Use

```
if (!d.children){
    alert(d.id);
}
```

This is because `d.children` would be `undefined` but you were checking for `null`. Since `undefined` and `null` equate to `false` `!d.children` check will succeed.

Comment: Oh Thanks I got it now :-) It works perfectly as I expected... By the way why it succeed on my second click? could you explain?

Comment: Like I mentioned before, first time the value of `d._children` is `undefined` and that gets set to d.children. So d.children(undefined) is not null. After this `d._children = null` gets executed and is set to `null`. Second time when you click, `d._children` is null and that get set to d.children. So second time around, `d.children === null` get evaluated to true. Hence, the behaviour.